# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Port {http://tempuri.org/}WSHttpBinding_IDWService not found

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wsdl2java

I'm trying to consume a webservice in java, using a client generated from the wsdl file with wsdl2java.

I'm using Eclipse version Helios and jdk 1.6.0_20, and I've generated the .class files using wsld2java with the options:

"-d c:\WebServices\Generated -client -verbose -compile -autoNameResolution -p org.dwservice -sn DWService -wsdlLocation /WEB-INF/wsdl/DWService.wsdl c:\WebServices\DWService.wsdl"

I packed the resultant files into a .jar and added it to my project that compiles ok.
But when I try to use the webservice, I got the exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Port {http://tempuri.org/}WSHttpBinding_IDWService not found.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:311)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:302)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
at org.dwservice.DWService.getWSHttpBindingIDWService(DWService.java:63)
```

And this is my code:

```
import org.dwservice.*;
...

private DWService dwService = new DWService();
private IDWService iDWService = ***dwService.getWSHttpBindingIDWService()***;
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your Web-service port and WSDL accessible using the browser ?

Answer (score 8):

I know this post is over a year old, but it's a highly ranked search result for this error. I'm adding this answer for posterity.

Your wsdl2java command suggests your WSDL is local and you're packaging it into a web app. I suspect the app isn't finding the packaged WSDL at runtime.  One option is to load it as a Java resource and pass its location into your service's constructor:

```
QName qname = new QName("my.name.space", "myName");
URL wsdlLocation = MyServiceClient.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/wsdl/DWService.wsdl");

dwService = new DWService(wsdlLocation, qname);
```

If you use this approach, triple-check the path to your WSDL. It's easy for getResource() to silently fail, which will produce the same error.

Comment: Also: don't use relative path when creating client with wsdl2java, only absolute. So, not "../wsdl/x.wsdl", but "/usr/share/wsdl/x.wsdl".