# "Can not initialize the default wsdl from..." -- Why?

Tags: wsdl, cxf, pom.xml, wsdl2java

My `pom.xml` contains the following to auto generate a client for a working web service having the WSDL specified below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/myclient.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                                <wsdlLocation>wsdl/myclient.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The project builds fine, without any errors or warnings and I can see the the file `myclient.wsdl` in the JAR file right under a `wsdl` folder.

But when I try running that JAR:

```
  java -Xmx1028m -jar myclient-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

It complains that "Can not initialize the default wsdl from wsdl/myclient.wsdl"

**Why?**

**What am I missing?**

How can I find out **what path** that `wsdl/myclient.wsdl` in pom.xml **translates into**, that makes the client's JAR complain at run time?

**Update:** I am aware of some solutions/workarounds that involve modifying the auto-generated code:

1. Pass "null" for the wsdl URL and then use the  ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().[put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977713/1864054), "http://example.com/....") to set the address.
2. load the WSDL as a Java resource and [pass its location into your service's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555346/1864054).

But I am more interested in a solution that requires entering the right values into the `pom.xml` like the [classpath approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875701/1864054) (but unfortunately classpath didn't work for me for some reason).

Any ideas what I should be typing there instead? Apparently this is a very simply case of figuring out the correct path rules for that particular plugin, but I am missing something and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice the [cfx examples](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) use slightly different locations for `sourceRoot`, `wsdl` and `wsdlLocation`.

Remember that typically, files in `src/main/resources` are included in the produced artifact. In order for files in `src/main/wsdl` to be included, it needs to be added as a resource in the pom.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/wsdl</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Tips:

- Set the paths you suspect to known bad paths and see if you get the same error-message.
- Unzip the produced `*.jar`-file(s) and check if the wsdl is included, and what the path is.

Comment: +1 and accepted because that's exactly what I did to solve my problem. However, it is still a mystery to me **how** to find out what path that wsdl/myclient.wsdl in pom.xml translates into **at run time?**

Answer (score 5):

The error comes from the static initializer of your generated service class (which is annotated by @WebServiceClient). It tries to load the wsdl file as resource. The generator uses the value which you have provided by the parameter wsdlLocation. You should leave away the "wsdl/" prefix:

```
<wsdlLocation>myclient.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
```

because the wsdl is located directly in the root of the classpath folder.

BTW: If you omit the parameter <wsdlLocation> the value of the param <wsdl> is used (which is not correct at runtime in your case, but would be correct if the provided URL would be a remote URL address, i.e. directly fetched from the webservice server).

BTW2: Your workaround 2 is in fact +/- what the generated code of the service class does if you use the parameterless constructor.